# Pandas Running Total by Group, Time Interval

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to take a table of customer orders like this:

```
customer_id | order_date | amount
0           | 2020-03-01 | 10.00
0           | 2020-03-02 |  2.00
1           | 2020-03-02 |  5.00
1           | 2020-03-02 |  1.00
2           | 2020-03-08 |  2.00
1           | 2020-03-09 |  1.00
0           | 2020-03-10 |  1.00
```

And create a table calculating a running total by week. Something like:

```
order_week  |   0    |   1    |  2
2020-03-01  | 12.00  | 6.00   | 0.00
2020-03-08  | 13.00  | 7.00   | 2.00
```

Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Quang Hoang beautiful and concise. But did you want it in 7 days strictly or a week.

I had a go partitioning it in a week because wanted dates stated in your outcome to appear. Obviously @Quang Hoang experience unmatched. Feel free to criticize because I am learning

Coerce date to datetime and set the date to index

```
df['order_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
df.set_index(df['order_date'], inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['order_date'], inplace=True
```

Group by customer id while and resample on amount.

```
df.groupby('customer_id')['amount'].apply(lambda x:x.resample('W').sum()).unstack('customer_id',fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

Outcome

[image]

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: Happy I was of help

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])

(df.groupby(['customer_id',df.order_date.dt.floor('7D')])
   .amount.sum()
   .unstack('customer_id',fill_value=0)
   .cumsum()
)
```

Output:

```
customer_id     0    1    2
order_date                 
2020-02-27   12.0  6.0  0.0
2020-03-05   13.0  7.0  2.0
```

Comment: I just found an issue where if there is a big gap in orders (e.g. a month), the output will skip weeks... any magic to deal with that scenario?